# How to use color() instead of facet_grid() to 'split' your data but keep it on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble substituting color() for facet_grid() when I want to 'split' my data by a variable. Instead of generating individual plots with regression lines, I'm looking to generate a single plot with all regression lines.

Here's my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Rooms, y = Price)) +
    geom_point(size = 1, alpha = 1/100) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = Type) # Single plot with all regression lines
ggplot(data, aes(x = Rooms, y = Price)) +
    geom_point(size = 1, alpha = 1/100) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") + facet_grid(. ~ Type) # Individual plots with regression lines
```

(The first plot doesn't work) Here's the output:
"Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'Type'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 12750 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth). 
2: Removed 12750 rows containing missing values (geom_point)."

Here's a link to the data:
[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/anthonypino/melbourne-housing-market)

Comment: It's good to post reproducible data, but you didn't wrap your `colour` argument inside `aes` and instead passed it to `geom_smooth` directly.

Comment: Sure thing, I've added output and a link to the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply an aesthetic mapping to `geom_smooth`, not just a parameter, which means you need to put `colour` inside `aes()`. This is what you need to do any time you want to have an graphical element correspond to something in the data rather than a fixed parameter.

Here's an example with the built-in `iris` dataset. In fact, if you move `colour` to the `ggplot` call so it is inherited by `geom_point` as well, then you can colour the points as well as the lines.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = Species), method = "lm")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).